# How to execute a PHP file in background for every 30 seconds

Tags: php

I am working on flight portal.

If any user book a ticket he/she will get some status like **BOOKING SUCCESS** / **BOOKING PENDING**.

If the status is **BOOKING SUCCESS** the user will get a mail with the ticket details.

In case of **BOOKING PENDING** a message ( your ticket is in process, you receive a message/email after the ticket confirmed) will be shown to the User.

Now from the backend i have to run a PHP file for every 30 seconds Until i get the status Success.

This will be a continuous process.

Can anyone tell me with a good example.

I will be thankful,

Sowmya

Comment: Use `AJAX` and poll a PHP script for status every 30 seconds

Comment: Cronjob is the way to go ;)

Comment: You can use CRON job, to schedule your task/php page for every 30 seconds.

Comment: Or just send the email when the backend user changes the status to success?

Comment: @Darhazer,Jahanzeb    Can i expect any example..I am new to those concepts.

Comment: It's worth noting that the minimum time that cron can handle is just 1 minute, not less. So you could only execute the php script once in a minute, not once every 30 seconds.

Comment: They're not going to write code for you when you don't have any presented

Comment: @PRPGFerret : Ok fine i will go through the documentation

Answer (score 18):

You are looking for [CRON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron), this helps you to schedule your task at your scheduled time.
That is your could execute/run your PHP script at the time scheduled by you.

```
* * * * * /path/to/php_file
* * * * * sleep 15; /path/to/php_file
* * * * * sleep 30; /path/to/php_file
* * * * * sleep 45; /path/to/php_file
```

The above cron job will run your php script for every 15 seconds. Here `sleep` will help to delay the script for every `15` seconds.

Comment: can i expect a example from you..?

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways of doing so.

The best way would be using a using a [Cron Job](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

Other ways are using a webworker or a an AJAX request, but those require a browser to be active at all times.

[Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job) you can find how to set it up.

As for a [webworker](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/), it's an HTML 5 feature so it wouldn't be adviced if you expect people using browsers that don't support it.

If your server runs on cPanel, you can easily set up a cron job. Otherwise you'd have to do it through your terminal I think or through your hosting provider if you have paid hosting without cPanel.

You can set up the cron job like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mb0J1.jpg), the command used in the bar is
`/path/to/php -q /absolute/path/to/your/phpfile.php >/dev/null`

Comment: can i expect a example from you..?

Comment: I linked an article for you, check my answer for it.

Comment: Yes My server is working on Cpanel. How to set up a corn job using that..?

Comment: You go to "Cron Job" under the advanced tab or search for "cron" in the search bar, there you can set it up using Linux commands. It should look like this: http://imgur.com/C2oItMH

Comment: i have my PHP file in this path. www.udoo.in/cron.php

Now i am giving the path like below..

home/udoo/public_html/cgi-bin/cron.php >/dev/null

Is it correct..?

Comment: It should be something along the lines of `/root/www/cron.php`. So yes, that should be correct. If you want to be absolutely sure you could check like this: `var_dump(file_exists('/home/udoo/public_html/cgi-bin/cron.php'));`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32324/discussion-between-sowmya-and-richard-a)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just reload your page you can use Javascript to achieve this.

**Plain JavaScript**

```
setTimeout(function() {
     window.location.reload();
},  30000);
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
    setTimeout(function() { 
        window.location.reload();
    },  30000);
});
```

Otherwise, you can use CURL. [Visit here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job) to get to know about usage of CURL.

Comment: @Sowmya CRON is also the best option but if you are getting any trouble in setting the cron than you can do it with OMAR's Code.

Comment: I would go for the plain JS.

Comment: But, you should opt for cron to run a script from background.